# Radio Button Yes or No call to JavaScript Visible or Hidden Select List

Tags: javascript, radio-button

When either radio button is pressed there is no change in the visibility of select tag. Simply nothing happens, not even errors.

This is my first attempt at using JavaScript and I have spent about 4 days now looking at a variety of examples to do this. I feel my syntax and the placement of everything is correct. I'm lost as to what I can possibly be missing.

Using the "Inspect Element Q" Inspector tab, when the radios are checked there is no change in anything. I just thought about it. I don't know how to use the debugger.

Before I published this here I put the code posted here into the JSfiddle. It runs there: turning the drop list on and off. So, might be something else in my PHP page.

Here is my code:

```
 <head> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function hasClass(){
        
            var checked_yes = document.getElementById("hasClass_yes").checked;
            var checked_no =  document.getElementById("hasClass_no").checked;
        
            if(checked_yes) {
                document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="visible";
            } else if(checked_no){
                document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="hidden";
                }
        }     
     </script>
     </head>



   <tr>
    <td>Does the monster have a class?
        <label for="hasClass_yes">Yes
            <input type="radio" id="hasClass_yes" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClass();" />
        </label>
            
        <label for="hasClass_no">No
            <input type="radio" id="hasClass_no" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClass();" />
        </label>
            
                       
        <select style="visibility:" id="class_drop_list" name="monsters_class">
            <option value="Adept">Adept</option>
            <option value="Barbarian">Barbarian</option>
            <option value="Cavalier">Cavalier</option>
            <option value="Cleric">Cleric</option>
            <option value="Druid">Druid</option>
            <option value="Healer">Healer</option>
            <option value="Jumper">Jumper</option>
            <option value="Marshalist">Marshalist</option>
            <option value="Rogue">Rogue</option>
            <option value="Rook">Rook</option>
            <option value="Sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
            <option value="Swashbuckler">Swashbuckler</option>
            <option value="Witch">Witch</option>
            <option value="Wizard">Wizard</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I have also tried this script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function hasClass(){
        
            var checked_yes = document.getElementById("hasClass_yes");
            var class_drop_list_on =  document.getElementById("class_drop_list");
        
            class_drop_list_on.style.visibility = checked_yes.checked ? "visibility" : "visible";
        }     
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working as a snippet.  what's the problem?

```html
<head> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function hasClass(){
        
            var checked_yes = document.getElementById("hasClass_yes").checked;
            var checked_no =  document.getElementById("hasClass_no").checked;
        
            if(checked_yes) {
                document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="visible";
            } else if(checked_no){
                document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="hidden";
                }
        }     
     </script>
     </head>



   <tr>
    <td>Does the monster have a class?
        <label for="hasClass_yes">Yes
            <input type="radio" id="hasClass_yes" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClass();" />
        </label>
            
        <label for="hasClass_no">No
            <input type="radio" id="hasClass_no" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClass();" />
        </label>
            
                       
        <select style="visibility:" id="class_drop_list" name="monsters_class">
            <option value="Adept">Adept</option>
            <option value="Barbarian">Barbarian</option>
            <option value="Cavalier">Cavalier</option>
            <option value="Cleric">Cleric</option>
            <option value="Druid">Druid</option>
            <option value="Healer">Healer</option>
            <option value="Jumper">Jumper</option>
            <option value="Marshalist">Marshalist</option>
            <option value="Rogue">Rogue</option>
            <option value="Rook">Rook</option>
            <option value="Sorcerer">Sorcerer</option>
            <option value="Swashbuckler">Swashbuckler</option>
            <option value="Witch">Witch</option>
            <option value="Wizard">Wizard</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: At this point I am thinking there is some issue with my system. I have tried the following: 1. checked in FireFox config and JavaScript is enabled, so thats no the problem. 2. Placed the relevent code in an html file all by itself, so only the script and the drop down menu are present. Still same problem. I have also tried several variations of a script and no change. So, I could use some advice on how to debug the javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have done the following trying to solve this.

1. Copied the relevant code from the php file into a separate html file to test it outside of the larger php file. Just the script and the yes/no inputs, and select tag .
2. It still did not work.
3. Installed another browser on my system - Chromium. The test file did not run there either.
4. Copied the test file and the original php file to usb and tried it on a windows computer. Still did not run there.
5. Modified the test file to be as it is below - and it has worked in all browsers on both Windows and Ubuntu computers.

   ```
    <html>
        <head>
           <style></style>

           <script type="text/javascript">

               function hasClassYes(){
            document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="visible";
        }                
               function hasClassNo(){
            document.getElementById("class_drop_list").style.visibility="hidden";
        }

           </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <form action="make_monster.php" method="post">
                <table>
                   <tr style="background-color:#999999">
                      <td>Does the monster have a class?

                          <label for="hasClass_yes">Yes
                              <input type="radio" id="hasClass_yes" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClassYes();" />
                          </label>

                          <label for="hasClass_no">No
                              <input type="radio" id="hasClass_no" name="hasClass" onclick="hasClassNo();" />
                          </label>


                          <select style="visibility:" id="class_drop_list" name="monsters_class">
                            <option value="Adept">Adept</option>
                            <option value="Barbarian">Barbarian</option>
                            <option value="Wizard">Wizard</option>
                          </select>
                       </td>    
                     <tr>

             </table>
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
   ```

What's different is that instead of using IF or SWITCH statements inside the same function to determine the state of yes no and set the style attribute in the select tag, I now have two separate functions for yes or no.